# PHP 5 login "syntax error, unexpected '?' " while using ?? operator

Tags: php, php-5.5, null-coalescing

This code is part of the login form, and I want to make sure that the field is not blank. When I am using this line of code I get the following error:

`syntax error, unexpected '?'`

```
 if(is_blank($admin['username'])) {
      $errors[] = "Username cannot be blank.";
    } elseif (!has_length($admin['username'], array('min' => 8, 'max' => 255))) {
      $errors[] = "Username must be between 8 and 255 characters.";
    } elseif (!has_unique_username($admin['username'], $admin['id'] ?? 0)) {
      $errors[] = "Username not allowed. Try another.";
    }
```

I know that I get the error because I am working with PHP 5.5.

Thank you!

Comment: Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use the following statement:

```
 (isset($admin['id']) ? $admin['id'] : 0 )
```

Since *PHP 5.5* doesn't have the `??` `null coalesce operator` (PHP 7 and higher) you need to do the old fashioned short hand.

Please not that I put it between brackets so it doesn't fail when it's within 
if or else statements and/or functions.

You could also use

```
$admin['id'] ?: 0;
```

But this will give notice when `$admin['id']` isn't set.